# 'SLS_DEBUG' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, windows, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I can able to deploy my serverless app on aws lambda using command 
 
    `sls deploy`,
 and this is working fine but when i try to debug using below command from command line 
`SLS_DEBUG=* sls deploy`
its showing 
`SLS_DEBUG' is not recognized as an internal or external command`
Note - I'm using window 10

Answer (score 0):

SLS_DEBUG is an environment variable, therefore if you use windows - you have to set it in a windows way. In powershell, for example, it would look like this:

`$env:SLS_DEBUG = '*'; sls deploy`